# site php hangs when calling exe file

Tags: php, windows, exec

I need to call an exe file (using some dll compiled in VS2010 in c#) in php to get some calculations.
When I do so from terminal

```
D:\somepath\D_Csharp.exe "0" "SZ084-4" "R407C" "10" "40" "2" "8" "8"
```

the exe file works just fine and outputs a short string.

But when I call it from php like

```
echo exec('D:\somepath\D_Csharp.exe  "0" "SZ084-4" "R407C" "10" "40" "2" "8" "8"');
```

the site continues to load the page and does nothing until I interupt it.

It is worth mentioning that some other exe file compiled in the same Visual Studio written in C++ works fine from php. I have also given all the rights to all users to the binary file.

System: Windows NT LMESERV03 6.1 build 7601 (Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition Service Pack 1) i586

Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler

Please help to solve this problem.

Comment: When you run it from command line what user are you running it as? When the php tries to run it it will most likely be a different user

Comment: As I said, I grunted all rights to all users on the pc to that particular binary file